# Tensor power of 1D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensor, broadcast

I would like to implement a function that takes what I call the "tensor power" of an one-dimensional numpy array:

```
def tensor_pow(x: np.ndarray, n: int) -> np.ndarray:
    
    # code goes here

    return y
```

For any numpy array `x` of shape `(Nx)`, the output `y` should be a numpy array of shape `(Nx, ..., Nx)` where there are `n` copies of `Nx`, and its entries are defined as `y[i, j, ..., k] = x[i] * x[j] * ... * x[k]`. A simple example would be:

```
y = tensor_pow(np.arange(3), 2)  # an array of shape (3, 3)
y[1, 2] == 2                     # returns True
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot avoid an explicit loop over `n`. If the tensor becomes large, you may want some more complex structure that makes use of the permutation symmetries.

```py
def tensor_pow(x, n):
    y = x
    for i in range(1, n):
        y = y[..., None] * x 
    return y
```